# Lubuntu 18.10 not booting completely after upgrade

Tags: lubuntu

I upgraded my lubuntu 18.04 to the newest 18.10 version -- I started the upgrade in the terminal with `sudo apt-get upgrade`.

When I rebooted the only thing I got was an empty desktop with the new wallpaper. No icons, no task bar. Nothing. I can't even access the terminal with  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>t</kbd>.

Comment: VTLO because Lubuntu 18.10 uses LXQt desktop environment by default.

Comment: @anto10 can you try the solutions suggested in the two possible duplicate questions? If they don't work, update your question to include a description of exactly what you did (not "tried the solution" -- reiterate the steps you took) and what result you got or didn't get.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, sometimes things break when doing an upgrade. I don't do that anymore because a similar situation happened to me. I just don't trust an upgrade. The only thing I can think of is to do a fresh install. Like I said I have had this happen. It also taught me a lesson, always backup your data.